# array_map on collection with array interfaces?

Tags: php, arrays, iterator, array-map

I have a class called `Collection` which stores objects of same type.
`Collection` implements array interfaces: `Iterator`, `ArrayAccess`, `SeekableIterator`, and `Countable`.

I'd like to pass a `Collection` object as the array argument to the [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function. But this fails with the error

> PHP Warning:  array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array

Can I achieve this by implementing other/more interfaces, so that `Collection` objects are seen as arrays?

Comment: Roll your own collection_map function?

Comment: @Adder Course I can, but now I'm looking for solution if I can use my Collection with buildin php funcs:)

Answer (score 32):

The `array_map()` function doesn't support a `Traversable` as its array argument, so you would have to perform a conversion step:

```
array_map($fn, iterator_to_array($myCollection));
```

Besides iterating over the collection twice, it also yield an array that will not be used afterwards.

Another way is to write your own map function:

```
function map(callable $fn)
{
    $result = array();

    foreach ($this as $item) {
        $result[] = $fn($item);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**Update**

Judging by your use-case it seems that you're not even interested in the result of the map operation; therefore it makes more sense to use [`iterator_apply()`](http://php.net/iterator_apply).

```
iterator_apply($myCollection, function($obj) {
    $obj->method1();
    $obj->method2();

    return true;
});
```

Comment: This does work, but has a performance penalty because it will iterate during the iterator_to_array step and it will iterate again during the array_map step.

Comment: @EelkevandenBos I gave two solutions in my answer, the latter not exhibiting this "performance penalty"; besides that, in both cases the runtime is O(n).

Comment: I think the callback to iterator_apply does not receive the current instance as an argument. From the docs: "This function only receives the given args, so it is nullary by default." The example in the docs solves this by passing the iterator itself as an argument and using $iterator->current().
Docs: https://php.net/iterator_apply

Comment: @Ole thanks for that, it may have been an oversight when i authored my update

Answer (score 9):

`array_map` wants, as the name suggests, *arrays*. It's not called `iterator_map` after all. ;)

Apart from `iterator_to_array()`, which produces a potentially large temporary array, there's no trick to make iterable objects work with `array_map`.

The [Functional PHP](https://github.com/lstrojny/functional-php) library has a `map` implementation which works on any iterable collection.

Comment: The Functional PHP map implementation is not memory efficient: the results are stored in array. I found a better library: https://github.com/SuRaMoN/itertools And a blog post explaining how you can build it yourself: http://www.a-basketful-of-papayas.net/2012/07/what-iterators-can-do-for-you.html

Comment: Aad, in general the result of a map function is a *new* array — the memory overhead is innate to the approach and is negligible in the vast majority of use cases.

Comment: "There's no trick to make iterable objects work with `array_map`." That trick is `iterator_to_array()`.

Comment: @MarkFox If the iterator yields a large collection of large arrays or objects, and the callable is intended to summarize each of them into a smaller array, object, or primitive, the memory overhead of first calling `iterator_to_array()` can be substantial.

Answer (score 4):

If you're **not** interested in creating a new array that is a function mapped over the original array, you could just use a foreach loop (because you implement `Iterator`).

```
foreach($item in $myCollection) {
    $item->method1();
    $item->method2();
}
```

if you actually want to use map, then I think you'll have to implement your own. I would suggest making it a method on Collection, eg:

```
$mutatedCollection = $myCollection->map(function($item) { 
    /* do some stuff to $item */
    return $item;
});
```

I would ask yourself if you really want to use `map` or do you really just mean `foreach`

Answer (score 3):

I came up with the following solution:

```
//lets say you have this iterator
$iterator = new ArrayIterator(array(1, 2, 3));

//and want to append the callback output to the following variable
$out = [];

//use iterator to apply the callback to every element of the iterator
iterator_apply(
    $iterator,
    function($iterator, &$out) {
        $current = $iterator->current();
        $out[] = $current*2;
        return true;
    },
    array($iterator, &$out) //arguments for the callback
);

print_r($out);
```

This way, you can generate an array without iterating twice as you would to with the approach like:

```
$iterator = new ArrayIterator(array(1,2,3));
$array = iterator_to_array($iterator); //first iteration
$output = array_map(function() {}, $array); //second iteration
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this question and I managed to cast the collection to an array to make it work:

```
array_map($cb, (array) $collection);
```

**disclaimer** For the original question this might not be a suitable option but I found the question while looking to solve a problem which I solved with this solution. I would recommend using  a custom iterator map where possible/viable.

another option is to do something like this:

```
foreach($collection as &$item) {
    $item = $cb($item);
}
```

which will mutate the underlying collection.

EDIT:

It has been pointed out that casting to an array can have unwanted side effects. It would be better to add a method to your collection to return the array from the iterator, and traverse that, or otherwise add a `map` method which accepts a callback and run a loop on the underlying iterator.

Comment: Blind casting to an array has the potential for nasty side-effects since you might end up with other data from the object in what gets iterated, instead of just getting the data that the iterator object is wrapping/navigating.

Comment: I agree with the principle, however since the object is a collection, the assumption being made was that there was no other data being bound to the object.

Comment: Given the interfaces implemented in the original question, it’s safe to assume that casting to an array would return an array representation of the iterator, however I have edited my answer to account for instances where people are trying to iterate over classes that do not implement the interfaces in OP