# What Interface to implement so an object behave like an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a Collection class that holds data as an array internally.

```
class Collection implements \IteratorAggregate, \Countable, \ArrayAccess
{
...
}
```

At some point in the code, following is happening

```
$list = new Collection([]);

array_map(function(Object $v){ return $v->getKey(); }, $list);
```

I thought implementing ArrayAccess should be enough to make an object behave like an array. IN thins case I have other implemented aS well, but clearly php uses some other mechanism to detect if the argument passed is an array as I am getting the

```
array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array
```

Comment: array_map really only takes arrays as far as I know. I don't think you can use it with other things just by making them iterable/array accessible.

Comment: I think this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273233/array-map-on-collection-with-array-interfaces

Comment: Thanks  iterator_to_array($list) worked.